# Can we pass data from textbox to node js without form action submit?

Tags: html, node.js, ejs

Hi everyone I want to pass some data from text field as soon as html page loads to node js without any form action submit. Is it possible in node js. I am using only ejs writimg html codes no react and angular

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take a tour at [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: As @Teasel suggest, you should follow those lines. Plus you should tell us if you're using angular or angularjs (components vs controller)